# app package built by pyinstaller fails after it uses tqdm

Tags: python, pyinstaller, tqdm

I have a program which can optionally use tqdm to display a progress bar for long calculations.
I've packaged the program using pyinstaller.
The packaged program runs to completion just fine if I don't enable tqdm.
If I enable tqdm, the package works fine and displays progress bars until it gets to the very end, then the message below is displayed and the packaged program is relaunched (with the wrong args).

> multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py:104: UserWarning: resource_tracker:
> process died  unexpectedly, relaunching.  Some resources might leak.

There is nothing fancy about the way the program invokes tqdm.
There is a loop that iterates over the members of a list.
The program does not import the multiprocessing module.

```
    def best_cost(self, guesses, steps=1, verbose=0) -> None:
        """ find the guess with the minimum cost """
        self.cost = float("inf")
        for guess in guesses if verbose < 3 else tqdm(guesses, mininterval=1.0):
            groups = dict()
            for (word, frequency) in self.words.items():
                result = calc_result(guess, word)
                groups.setdefault(result, {})[word] = frequency
            self.check_cost(guess, groups, steps=steps)
        return
```

The problem occurs whether pyinstaller creates the package with --onedir or --onefile.
I'm running on MACOS Monterey V12.4 on an Intel processor.
I'm using python 3.10.4, but the problem also occurs with 3.9. Pip installed packages include: pyinstaller 5.1, pyinstaller-hooks-contrib 2022.7, and tqdm 4.64.0.
I package the program in a virtualenv.

I found this in the documentation for the multiprocessing module:

> On Unix using the spawn or forkserver start methods will also start a resource tracker process which tracks the unlinked named system resources (such as named semaphores or SharedMemory objects) created by processes of the program. When all processes have exited the resource tracker unlinks any remaining tracked object. Usually there should be none, but if a process was killed by a signal there may be some “leaked” resources. (Neither leaked semaphores nor shared memory segments will be automatically unlinked until the next reboot. This is problematic for both objects because the system allows only a limited number of named semaphores, and shared memory segments occupy some space in the main memory.)

I can't figure out how to debug the the problem since it only occurs with the pyinstaller packaged program and my IDE (vscode) doesn't help.
My program doesn't use the multiprocessing module.
The tqdm documentation doesn't mention issues like this, but it does include the multiprocessing module to create locks (semaphores) in the tqdm class which
get used by the instances.
There aren't any tqdm methods I can find to delete the semaphores resources;
I guess that is just supposed to happen automatically when the program ends.
I think the pyinstaller packaged program may also use the multiprocessing
module.
Perhaps pyinstaller is interfering with deletion of the tqdm semaphores somehow?

The packaged program works fine till it starts to exit and then gets restarted.
Does anyone know how I can get the packaged program to exit cleanly?

Comment: I am encountering the same problem. I assumed the multiprocessing issue was down to how I was using it, but it occurs even when I've eliminated all multiprocessing code from my package. This issue disappears when I remove TQDM. Frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

There is already an [issue](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/1355)

I don't know how to fix it, but I find the following code can help suppress the warning for me:

```py
import warnings
from multiprocessing import freeze_support

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
freeze_support()
```

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the answer but I can't check it out since I no longer use pyinstaller.